# Prove that function $f$ is continuous at $x = x_{0}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

In class we're given the following definition about continuity, and I want to apply this definition to the problems that follow:

$f$ is continuous at $x_{0} \in \mathrm{dom}(f)$ if $\forall x_{n} \in \mathrm{dom}(f)$ that's converging to $x_{0}$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n}) = f(x_{0})$

$1). $ Prove that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x_{0} = 0$.

Suppose $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_{n}) = 0$, then

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x_{n}} = (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n})^{\frac{1}{2}} = 0^{\frac{1}{2}} = f(x_{0})$

And note that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x_{n}} = (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ holds because $f$ is a continuous function. From my understanding, I can apply the algebraic limit theorem only if the function is continuous, correct? But here I'm using it as part of my proof to show that the function is continuous at $0$. Is this a problem? Or can the algebraic limit theorem be applied regardless of continuity?

$2).$ Prove that $f(x) = \begin{cases}
x \sin(\frac{1}{x})) & \text{ if } x \neq 0 \\ 
0 & \text{ otherwise }  
\end{cases}$

Suppose $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n} = 0$, then

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0 = 0 = f(x_{0})$

Would this suffice? Should I also take into account that $x_{n}$ might consist of $x \neq 0$?

Comment: In the first problem you claim that $\lim_\sqrt{x_n}=(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n)^{1/2}$ because $f$ is continuous.  Correct me if I'm missing something, but $f(x)=\sqrt x$. This is the function whose continuity you are trying to prove.  It seems that your reasoning is circular.

Comment: If you have learnt $\epsilon- \delta$ argument, it is always better to use that since that is really a rigorous proof.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski I see. THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question: no, because the property $\lim \sqrt{x_n}=\sqrt{\lim x_n}$ can be proved by definition of limit of sequence. Indeed, if $x_n\ge 0$ for all $n$ and $\lim x_n=L\ge 0$ then $\lim \sqrt{x_n}=\sqrt{L}$. If $L=0$, for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $x_n<\varepsilon^2$ for all $n>N$, then $\sqrt{x_n}<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$, thus $\lim \sqrt{x_n}=0$. If $L>0$, we have $|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{L}|=\frac{|x_n-L|}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{L}}<\frac{|x_n-L|}{\sqrt{L}}$, so $\lim \sqrt x_n=\sqrt{L}$.

For your second one, yes, $x_n\neq 0$ for all $n$, since this is the definition of continuity of a function: $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if for all sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\neq x_0$, $\lim f(x_n)=f(x_0)$.

Due to my experience, it's often easier to use the above definition to prove the continuity of function than the $\varepsilon-\delta$ one.